# Updating Django Database - Script

Tags: python, database, django, api, persistence

So I am a newbie in Django, and I am working on an app that uses a script which uses an external API to get data in the form of a Python dictionary, at which point this data is loaded into my Django database, and finally, the database is displayed in an HTML table. Here's where I am confused: I'm running this script in views.py, as such:

```
def index(request):
    data = get_data()
    #print data
    for x in data:
            (newModel1, s_created) = Model1.objects.get_or_create(model1_name = x)
            if s_created:
                    newModel1.save()
            for y in data[x]:
                    (newModel2, b_created) = Model2.objects.get_or_create(model2_name=y)
                    if b_created:
                            newModel2.save()

    return render_to_response('jenkins_slog/index.html', {'servers': Server$
'''
```

I obviously don't want to run this script every time the page is loaded, because that would be hideously inefficient. Where do scripts like this go so that they are updated, say, every five minutes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatives are many, lets list my favorites:

- [Management command and call by cron](https://coderwall.com/p/k5p6ag)
- [Celery periodic tasks](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html)